# How can I get the data from my controller into my View via Ajax while returning a View?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have this action in my controller which is returning a View...

```
public ActionResult SaveTimeShift(...)
        {
            try
            {

                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    return PartialView(....);

                return View(userRecord);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {                
                return PartialView(...);
            }
        }
```

Then this the html code in my viewpage...

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTimeShift", new { }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "recordList", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, Confirm = "Do you want to save the new time shift?",  OnSuccess = "partialRequestSuccess(data)", OnFailure = "partialRequestFailure" }, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
        {
```

Now on my partialRequestSuccess(data) function on my OnSuccess parameter of AjaxOptions...

```
function partialRequestSuccess(data) {
    if (data == 1)
        alert("New Time Shift has been saved.");
}
```

Now my problem here is .... Im trying to set a value of my "data" variable that will be set in my controller... I did some research about returning a Json object unfortunately I'm returning a View in my controller... For now my "data" variable has a garbage value...Is there a way of knowing from my client side if my saving of data in the database was a success or not... Thanks! :)

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to return from your controller? A JSON object or HTML?

Comment: You want to return HTML from Controller and get something different in JS callback? :)

Comment: what im trying to do is passed some kind of data telling my client side that saving of data in my controller part is a success... while returning an html page... then an alert will pop-up based on the data passed that the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data in your model or ViewBag in the action method:

```
ViewBag.MyVariable = "myValue";
```

then use in in the JavaScript

```
var myVariable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MyVariable))
```

Comment: sorry but no success... maybe bcoz im return an ajax request thus a partial view was rendered instead of the view designated in the action controller that's why viewbag data is somewhat reset...